# Remove Background as Opacity

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to have an image over lap another image in VB.Net to create a honeycomb effect. I was able to get the code:

```
Me.Label1.BackColor = Color.Transpartent
```

to work but then it brings the actual background forward and over places the image it over laps. How can I get the image to not bring the background forward?

[image: Image Showing how the actual background over takes the image]

Comment: This would be far easier without the controls.  Just draw everything on a PictureBox.  WinForms has limited transparency abilities, as you found out.

Comment: @LarsTech Those are picture boxes with an image set in them.
Would you recommend using something different from the WinForms? Will eventually be having an SQL Database working with this.

Comment: Ummm if these are already picture boxes, why show us code for a label?  What does a sql database have to do with this?  Maybe a png image with a transparent background in the picture box might do what you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @Hursey I didn't realize I did that. I thought they were picture boxes. Either way with the picture box it does the same thing. These are also PNGs with the background removed.